# Using Mellin transform for a certain function

Tags: generating-functions, integral-transforms, catalan-numbers

In short, I want to use the Mellin transform to obtain the asymptotic behavior of the sequence $D_n = \frac{ [z^n] D(z)} {C_n}$ where 
$$
 D(z) =  \frac 1{2z}\sum_{p \ge 1}C_p \left( \sqrt{1-4z+4z^{p+1}}-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)
$$
and $C_n=\frac 1 {n+1} \binom{2n}n$ denotes the $n$-th Catalan number.

The generating function $D(z)$ describes the average size of the so-called *minimal directed acyclic graph* of a binary tree. It is taken from the paper [Analytic variations on the common subexpression problem](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0032034#page-1) and its asymptotic is there proven to be $2 \sqrt{\frac{\ln 4}{\pi}}\frac{n}{\sqrt{\ln n}}$.
However, since that proof is rather complicated (a detailed proof can be found in the appendix of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5927)), because the form of the generating function just screams for Mellin analysis via so-called *harmonic sums*, and lastly, because there is an analysis of the very similar generating function
$$
 U(z) = \frac 1{2}\sum_{p \ge 1}\left(\sqrt{1-4z+2^{p+1}z^{p+1}}-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)
$$
in [this paper by F. Disanto](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.5668v4.pdf), I believe that an analysis via Mellin is possible and insightful.

*Some background.* The main reference I used for Mellin transforms is the paper [Mellin transforms and asymptotics: Harmonic sums](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/mellin-harm.pdf).Harmonic sums are functions of the form
$$
 G(z) = \sum_{k } \lambda_k g(\mu_k z)
$$
and the aforementioned paper derives under which circumstances the Mellin transformation of those functions may be "factored" to the Mellin transform of the function $g(z)$ multiplied by the so-called *Dirichlet series*
$$
 \Lambda(s) = \lambda_k \mu_k^{-s}.
$$

*Where I got stuck*. I first carefully followed the paper by Disanto, but the derived function did not meet the requirements under which the function may be factored. [This resulted in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283419/a-mellin-transform-of-a-generating-function). However, I later noticed that I had made a mistake in the very beginning: Disanto replaces the term
$\sqrt{1-4z+2^{p+1}z^{p+1}}$ by $\sqrt{1-4z+2^{-p-1}}$, and shows that the induced error is bounded.
Yet in our case, if we replace $\sqrt{1-4z+4z^{p+1}}$ by $\sqrt{1-4z+4^{-p}}$, the corresponding error becomes infinite (this is caused by the Catalan series in the sum).

So I am looking for a different estimate of the term $\sqrt{1-4z+4z^{p+1}}$, possibly one that splits the $p$ away from the $z$, as I think that's the best way to later be able to factor the Dirichlet series away from the base function.